# Entity Framework Plus Batch Delete on DateTime Not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-plus

I have run into a scenario where I need to bulk delete on a specific date time.  It seems that the EF+ batch delete function doesn't correctly equate date time and perform the action.

It does work fine on other field types, but just not DateTime.  Is there some special formatting I should be doing to perform this action properly?

The backend SQL Server table has the `FileCreatedDate` as `DateTime2(7)`.  And records all contain the `DateTime.UtcNow` date/time that is specified in the code, since an initial pass prior to this code created those records.  This is a fallback to clean out the records that got created if an error occurred.

I have the following code:

```
var fileCreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

using (var db = new MyContextDb())
{
    db.SampleModel.Where(e => e.FileCreatedDate == fileCreatedDate).Delete();
}
```

This code doesn't work. It doesn't delete the records whose time matches the criteria.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you are running into [this EF issue with datetime values](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/de5dbf3e-8c95-40f4-9e31-b71f1f31983d/change-in-datetime2-implementation-in-sql-server-2016?forum=transactsql) where EF does a cast to datetime2 for comparing to a datetime column column.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove the entities using range?

like so:

```
db.SampleModel.RemoveRange(db.SampleModel.Where(e => e.FileCreatedDate == fileCreatedDate));
db.SaveChanges();
```